# how to sort the timestamp object in an array that we get from firebase

Tags: android, sorting, timestamp

I am getting a set of data from firebase which is given bellow

i am taking this to my datasnapshot through a model class name - MyModelView

and i am taking this to an array - List mylistsort = new ArrayList<>();

i need to sort mylistsort with the timestamp which is the  -servervalue.Timestamp

i use the following code but it does not work

```
 namesSorted = names; // names is my list to be sorted i am taking it to nnnew array namessorted
    Collections.sort(namesSorted, new Comparator<MatchModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MatchModel o1, MatchModel o2) {
            return o1.getTimestamp().compareTo(o2.getTimestamp());
        }
    });
```

Comment: i think the problem is with your epoch(timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just query like this ,Use Query to query the data and perform orderByValue(). This always gives data in ascending order.

`Query chatQuery = yourdbReference.orderByChild("timestamp_now"). limitToLast(20)`;

Comment: i have already taken the data by a query. I need to sort this list now